# [HTML]How to create a link to link all email address in dropdown list?

Tags: html, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

First of all, I would like to create a dropdown list and having three options which is three different email address. After that, I want to create a word link name "**Send Email**" besides it and link to `mailto:xx@gmail.com` by default.

While I choose another person from the dropdown list, the link will change accordingly. However, now when I click the link, nothing pops out.

Which part goes wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
<select name="selectReceiver" id="emailSelector">
        <option value="mailto:xx@gmail.com" selected="selected">Mr.X</option>
        <option value="mailto:yy@gmail.com">Mr.Y</option>
        <option value="mailto:zz@gmail.com">Mr.Z</option>
</select>
<a id="sendButton" href="mailto:cwu@cs.hku.hk">Send Email</a>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code how you try to change the link href

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
function sendMail() {
  var emailTo = document.getElementById('emailSelector').value;
  
  window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo;
}
```

```html
<select name="selectReceiver" id="emailSelector">
        <option value="mailto:xx@gmail.com" selected="selected">Mr.X</option>
        <option value="mailto:yy@gmail.com">Mr.Y</option>
        <option value="mailto:zz@gmail.com">Mr.Z</option>
    </select>
    <a id="sendButton" href="javascript:sendMail()">Send Email</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe it is a stupid question but I am new to html. So when I click the link, will something pop out? Or it just nothing happen?

Comment: The default email software will pop-up with the email address in the TO: field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="selectReceiver" id="emailSelector" onchange="changeRef()">
    <option value="mailto:xx@gmail.com" selected="selected">Mr.X</option>
    <option value="mailto:yy@gmail.com">Mr.Y</option>
    <option value="mailto:zz@gmail.com">Mr.Z</option>
</select>
<a id="sendButton" href="mailto:cwu@cs.hku.hk">Send Email</a>

<script>
    function changeRef()
    {
        document.getElementById("sendButton").href = emailSelector.value;
    }

</script>
```